# database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: DELETE FROM users = UserModel@dff4685;

Tags: android

I need your help. I want to delete data from my Database by actionModeCallbacks inside the RecyclerView.

remove a users from my recyclerview/database.

This is my logcat.

```
 Process: com.andylab.recovermessages, PID: 24576
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: DELETE FROM users = com.andylab.recovermessages.models.UserModel@dff4685;
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:939)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:550)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1770)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1698)
    at com.andylab.recovermessages.db.recentNumberDB.deleteItem(recentNumberDB.java:367)
    at com.andylab.recovermessages.adapters.UsersAdapter$1.onActionItemClicked(UsersAdapter.java:70)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onActionItemClicked(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2171)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.StandaloneActionMode.onMenuItemSelected(StandaloneActionMode.java:141)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:981)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

2020-05-10 02:55:30.109 24576-24576/com.andylab.recovermessages I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24576 SIG: 9

This is my datadb.

```
private class datadb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ADDED_PACKAGES = "CREATE TABLE table_packages (ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, package TEXT unique);";
    static final String CREATE_TABLE_FILES = "CREATE TABLE files (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, files TEXT, whole_time LONG);";
    static final String CREATE_TABLE_MSG = "CREATE TABLE messeges (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, package TEXT, username TEXT, msg TEXT, small_time TEXT, whole_time LONG);";
    private static final String CREATE_TEBLE_COOL = "CREATE TABLE cool_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, cool_text TEXT unique);";
    private static final String CREATE_TEBLE_QUICK_REPLY = "CREATE TABLE quick_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, quick_reply TEXT);";
    private static final String CREATE_TEBLE_REPEATER = "CREATE TABLE repeater_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, text_repeater TEXT);";
    private static final String CREATE_TEBLE_UNSAVED = "CREATE TABLE num_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nums TEXT unique);";
    static final String CREATE_USER_WITH_ID = "CREATE TABLE users (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, package TEXT, username TEXT UNIQUE, read_unread boolean, whole_time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
    private static final String ID = "_id";
    private static final String NAME = "recover.db";
    private static final int version = 1;

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
    }

    public datadb(Context context) {
        super(context, NAME, null, version);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase) {
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TEBLE_UNSAVED);
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TEBLE_QUICK_REPLY);
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TEBLE_REPEATER);
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TEBLE_COOL);
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_USER_WITH_ID);
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MSG);
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FILES);
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ADDED_PACKAGES);
    }
}

public recentNumberDB(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public long addData(String str, String str2, String str3, String str4, String str5) {
    Long l = null;
    try {
        addUser(str2, str, str5);
        SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new datadb(this.context).getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username", str);
        contentValues.put("small_time", str4);
        contentValues.put("whole_time", str5);
        contentValues.put(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE, str3);
        contentValues.put("package", str2);
        l = writableDatabase.insert("messeges", null, contentValues);
        writableDatabase.close();
    } catch (Exception str6) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("error: ");
        stringBuilder.append(str6.toString());
        Log.d("dblog", stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    return l;
}

public void addUser(String str, String str2, String str3) {
    recentNumberDB view_deleted_messages_dbs_recentNumberDB = this;
    String str4 = str;
    String str5 = str2;
    String str6 = str3;
    String str7 = "package";
    String str8 = "read_unread";
    String str9 = "whole_time";
    String str10 = "username";
    String str11 = "addedusrsnum";
    Log.d(str11, "adding started");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("current time ");
    stringBuilder.append(str6);
    Log.d(str11, stringBuilder.toString());
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new datadb(view_deleted_messages_dbs_recentNumberDB.context).getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(str10, str5);
        contentValues.put(str9, str6);
        contentValues.put(str8, Boolean.valueOf(false));
        contentValues.put(str7, str4);
        String str12 = "users";
        if (writableDatabase.query("users", new String[]{str10, str7}, "username=? AND package=?", new String[]{str5, str4}, null, null, null).getCount() == 0) {
            writableDatabase.insert(str12, null, contentValues);
            Log.d(str11, "greater 0");
        } else {
            contentValues.clear();
            contentValues.put(str9, str6);
            contentValues.put(str8, Boolean.valueOf(false));
            writableDatabase.update(str12, contentValues, "username=? AND package=?", new String[]{str5, str4});
            Log.d(str11, "updates");
        }
        writableDatabase.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder2.append("error: ");
        stringBuilder2.append(e.toString());
        Log.d(str11, stringBuilder2.toString());
    }
}

public List<HashMap> getUsers(String str) {
    String str2 = "username";
    String str3 = "read_unread";
    List<HashMap> arrayList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = new datadb(this.context).getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = readableDatabase;
        Cursor query = sQLiteDatabase.query("users", new String[]{str3, str2}, "package=?", new String[]{str}, null, null, "whole_time DESC");
        while (query.moveToNext()) {
            HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
            Log.d("readunr", query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(str3)));
            hashMap.put("boolean", query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(str3)));
            hashMap.put("string", query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(str2)));
            arrayList.add(hashMap);
        }
        query.close();
        readableDatabase.close();
    } catch (Exception str4) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("error: ");
        stringBuilder.append(str4.toString());
        Log.d("dblog", stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    return arrayList;
}

public List<DataModel> getMsg(String str, String str2) {
    String str3 = "small_time";
    String str4 = NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE;
    List<DataModel> arrayList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new datadb(this.context).getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = writableDatabase;
        Cursor query = sQLiteDatabase.query("messeges", new String[]{str4, str3}, "username=? AND package=?", new String[]{str, str2}, null, null, null);
        while (query.moveToNext()) {
            arrayList.add(new DataModel(query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(str4)), query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(str3))));
        }
        query.close();
        writableDatabase.close();
    } catch (Exception str5) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("error: ");
        stringBuilder.append(str5.toString());
        Log.d("dblog", stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    return arrayList;
}

public boolean isPresent(String str, String str2, String str3) {
    recentNumberDB view_deleted_messages_dbs_recentNumberDB = this;
    String str4 = str;
    String str5 = NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE;
    String str6 = "dblog";
    boolean z = false;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = new datadb(view_deleted_messages_dbs_recentNumberDB.context).getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = readableDatabase;
        Cursor query = sQLiteDatabase.query("messeges", new String[]{str5}, "username=? AND package=?", new String[]{str4, str3}, null, null, "_id DESC", "1");
        if (query.getCount() > 0) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("isPresentusername=");
            stringBuilder.append(str4);
            stringBuilder.append("Size=");
            stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(query.getCount()));
            Log.d(str6, stringBuilder.toString());
            while (query.moveToNext()) {
                str4 = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(str5));
                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append("ispresend greater 0. chat = ");
                stringBuilder.append(str4);
                Log.d(str6, stringBuilder.toString());
                z = str4.equals(str2);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(str6, "ispresent is 0");
        }
        query.close();
        readableDatabase.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder2.append("error: ");
        stringBuilder2.append(e.toString());
        Log.d(str6, stringBuilder2.toString());
    }
    return z;
}

public List<UserModel> getHomeList(String s) {
    recentNumberDB view_deleted_messages_dbs_recentNumberDB = this;
    ArrayList<UserModel> list = new ArrayList<UserModel>();
    try {
        List<HashMap> users = this.getUsers(s);
        SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = new recentNumberDB.datadb(view_deleted_messages_dbs_recentNumberDB.context).getReadableDatabase();
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); ++i) {
            Cursor query = readableDatabase.query("messeges", new String[] { "msg", "small_time" }, "username=? AND package=?", new String[] { users.get(i).get("string").toString(), s }, (String)null, (String)null, "_id DESC", "1");
            if (query != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("users lenght ");
                sb.append(users.size());
                Log.d("emptylog", sb.toString());
                StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                sb2.append("cursor lenght ");
                sb2.append(String.valueOf(query.getCount()));
                Log.d("emptylog", sb2.toString());
                if (query.getCount() == 0) {
                    list.add(new UserModel(users.get(i).get("string").toString(), "no recent msg", "", 1));
                }
                else {
                    while (true) {
                        int moveToNext = query.moveToNext() ? 1 : 0;
                        if (moveToNext == 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        list.add(new UserModel(users.get(i).get("string").toString(), query.getString(0), query.getString(moveToNext), Integer.parseInt(users.get(i).get("boolean").toString())));
                        Log.d("emptylog", query.getString(0));
                    }
                }
                query.close();
            }
            else {
                Log.d("emptylog", "cursor null");
            }
        }
        readableDatabase.close();
        return list;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return list;
    }
}

public void addPackages(String s) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new recentNumberDB.datadb(this.context).getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("package", s);
        writableDatabase.insert("table_packages", (String)null, contentValues);
        writableDatabase.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllPackages() {
    String[] array = { "com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.w4b", "com.gbwhatsapp", "com.facebook.lite", "com.facebook.orca", "com.facebook.mlite", "org.telegram.messenger" };
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Cursor query = new recentNumberDB.datadb(this.context).getReadableDatabase().query("table_packages", new String[] { "package" }, (String)null, (String[])null, (String)null, (String)null, (String)null);
        boolean moveToNext;
        while (true) {
            moveToNext = query.moveToNext();
            if (!moveToNext) {
                break;
            }
            list.add(query.getString(0));
        }
        query.close();
        int n = moveToNext ? 1 : 0;
        int i;
        while (true) {
            i = (moveToNext ? 1 : 0);
            if (n >= array.length) {
                break;
            }
            if (list.contains(array[n])) {
                list2.add(array[n]);
            }
            ++n;
        }
        while (i < list.size()) {
            if (!list2.contains(list.get(i))) {
                list2.add(list.get(i));
            }
            ++i;
        }
        return list2;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return list2;
    }
}

public void removePackageAndMsg(ArrayList<String> list) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new recentNumberDB.datadb(this.context).getWritableDatabase();
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (true) {
            int hasNext = iterator.hasNext() ? 1 : 0;
            if (hasNext == 0) {
                break;
            }
            String s = iterator.next();
            String[] array = new String[hasNext];
            array[0] = s;
            writableDatabase.delete("table_packages", "package=?", array);
            String[] array2 = new String[hasNext];
            array2[0] = s;
            writableDatabase.delete("users", "package=?", array2);
            String[] array3 = new String[hasNext];
            array3[0] = s;
            writableDatabase.delete("messeges", "package=?", array3);
        }
        writableDatabase.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void remove(ArrayList<String> list) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new recentNumberDB.datadb(this.context).getWritableDatabase();
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (true) {
            int hasNext = iterator.hasNext() ? 1 : 0;
            if (hasNext == 0) {
                break;
            }
            String s = iterator.next();
            String[] array = new String[hasNext];
            array[0] = s;
            ///             writableDatabase.delete("table_packages", "package=?", array);
            String[] array2 = new String[hasNext];
            array2[0] = s;
            writableDatabase.delete("users", "package=?", array2);
            String[] array3 = new String[hasNext];
            array3[0] = s;
            writableDatabase.delete("messeges", "package=?", array3);
        }
        writableDatabase.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void deleteItem(UserModel position){
    SQLiteDatabase db = new recentNumberDB.datadb(this.context).getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + "users" + "package=?" + "username" + " = " + position + ";");
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + "messeges" + "package=?" + "small_time" + " = " + position + ";");
    db.close();
}
```

}

And this is my adapter

```
`public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <UsersAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private ArrayList <UserModel> list;
private ArrayList<UserModel> selectedItems = new ArrayList<UserModel>();
private String pack;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private boolean multiSelect = false;

private ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallbacks = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        multiSelect = true;
        menu.add("Delete");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        for (UserModel intItem : selectedItems) {
            list.remove(intItem);
            notifyDataSetChanged ();
            recentNumberDB recentNumberDB = new recentNumberDB(context);
            recentNumberDB.deleteItem ( intItem );
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_delete:
                return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        multiSelect = false;
        selectedItems.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

public void itemRemoved(int position) {
    recentNumberDB recentNumberDB = new recentNumberDB(context);

    list.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    recentNumberDB.deleteItem(position);

}

public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList <UserModel> list, String str) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = (ArrayList <UserModel>) list;
    this.pack = str;
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ConstraintLayout listt;
    TextView msg;
    TextView name;
    TextView readunread;
    TextView time;
    public ImageButton btn_delete;
    public CheckBox chkSelected;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        msg = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        listt = (ConstraintLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        readunread = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.unread);
        btn_delete = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_unit);
        chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chk_selected);
    }

    public void selectItem(UserModel list) {
        if (multiSelect) {
            if (selectedItems.contains(list)) {
                selectedItems.remove(list);
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                selectedItems.add(list);
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(final UserModel value) {
   //     textView.setText(value + "");
        if (selectedItems.contains(value)) {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        } else {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor( Color.WHITE);
        }
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                ((AppCompatActivity)view.getContext()).startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallbacks );
                selectItem(value);
                return true;
            }
        });
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectItem(value);
            }
        });
    }

}
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users_home, parent, false);

    RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    UserModel userModel = (UserModel) list.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(userModel.getName());
    holder.msg.setText(userModel.getLastmsg());
    holder.time.setText(userModel.getTime());
    holder.listt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (adCount%4==0){
                ///                  AdmobHelper.showInterstitialAd(context, AdmobHelper.ADSHOWN);
            }
            adCount++;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessegesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", userModel.getName());
            intent.putExtra("pack", pack);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    holder.update(list.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

}`

Comment: This question lacks of information. What action have you performed before the error? Show us the code, if possible.